# Java email and yahoo

Tags: java, yahoo-mail

I use my email server to send email. I can send my emails to gmail successfully(I can find my emails in my gmail spam folder) but when I wand to send yahoo mail my emails is not recieved by yahoomail
I check spam folder. but can not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure here, but I think Yahoo might block some mails completely if it thinks they are spam, i.e. they won't even show up in your spam folder. While I'm not sure about Yahoo, I know that MSN/Live behaves this way.

Comment: My ip is not mapped to a valid domain name which i use in my email address. Do you think it is effective on yahoo blocking

Comment: Yeah, I'd think that Yahoo would block such mails completely. Maybe Yahoo's Help page for Postmasters gives you more information: http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/